# Is WinSAT reliable to test the speed of my iSCSI, Fibre SAN, under bare metal or Virtualized?

Tags: windows, performance, storage-area-network, iscsi, hard-drive

I discovered the following command in [this whitepaper:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463388.aspx)

```
WinSat disk -read -ran -ransize 4096 -drive c
```

Is it reliable to use against a SAN, or iSCSI drive?  I would like to compare the output of various hosts.

Comment: would be nice if it worked on servers just to give a rough performance analysis..

Comment: Since WinSAT is geared towards client OSs it's probably not ideal for server infrastructure.  That said; I've never used it or even seen it before now.

Answer (score 0):

SQLIO is great for performing these kinds of tests.  Don't let the name fool you, it is not Sql Server specific.  You can use it to test various combinations of Reads vs Writes, Random vs Sequential IO. It supports arbitrary block sizes, numbers of threads and number of outstanding IOs across files of arbitrary size, so it is applicable to many different workload types.

It will give you IOPs, total throughput, and a histogram of latency statistics.  It's the best tool I've found to generate substantial IO load before going to production with new HW.